# What is Bower and how do I install using it ? Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Following this tutorial on 'context menu's' in d3:

'https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu'

It says to install with Bower. Now I googled it and followed this tutorial :

'http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-bower'

So installed Node.js and now I'm stuck. Where do I put the `bower install d3-context-menu` found in the first tutorial ?

And what is Bower ?

Comment: Once you have installed nodejs, install bower through npm.

Comment: Open a console/terminal and type `npm install d3-context-menu`.

Comment: @rekoDolph Use command prompt..not npm file

Comment: i get this problem now :( ''bower ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the Path '' ill google it now but if you know that will be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower is a package manager that downloads some web libraries to your host.

> Where do I put `bower install d3-context-menu` found in the first tutorial ?

In command prompt.

But firstly you need to install bower by

```
npm install bower
```

npm is node.js package manager (that installs node.js modules).

Comment: command promt - cmd for windows. May be [it (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41tpzACUOPo) helps you.

Comment: @rekoDolph, install git: http://git-scm.com/download/win